# jquery - adding a value to a list - rendering on the client side

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Using rails, I have created a displayed list and a textfield with a "add" button/link . 
I want to be able to add the value entered in the text field to the list - on the client side.
How can I do it?

or if I you can direct me to a link for further reading

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jQuery appendTo`  you can write something like this. http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/

```
val = $('#textbox').val();
$('<li>'+val+'</li>').appendTo('#your_ul_list');
```

You can play around with this.