# Use Jquery, pull text out of textfield and put it in unordered list onClick

Tags: jquery, html-lists, chat, textfield

I'm building a Chat. I need to use Jquery to pull the text the user enters into the textfield out of the textfield, and put it into my unordered list when the send button is clicked. Am I close at all?

my error is this(when I look in Chrome Dev tools): Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; but I can't figure out why, and if thats the only problem? I've looked over my code and it seems like everything is closed

I tried looking here: http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/    and at this SO post.

[jquery - adding a value to a list - rendering on the client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881240/jquery-adding-a-value-to-a-list-rendering-on-the-client-side)

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#sendButton").click(function(){
          $('#textbox').val());
            $('<li>'+val+'</li>').appendTo('#ulList');
        });
      };

    </script>


    <h2>Broken Chat</h2>

    <input id="textbox" class="draft" type="text"/> <button id="sendButton" class="send">send</button>

    <ul id="ulList" class="messages">
```

my latest effort was to try adding the following to my existing code:

```
<li id= "userMessage"></li>
```

and obviously change my append:

```
$('<li>'+val+'</li>').appendTo('#userMessage');
```

Last effort was:

```
 $('<ul>'+val+'</ul>').appendTo('#ulList');
 <ul id="ulList" class="messages">
```

I apologize if I asked a duplicate question, but I haven't found an answer that works. If you have found something else on this site please reference it.

Comment: Extra bracket in this line `$('#textbox').val());` and at ending of `document` function it should be `});` but not `};`.

Comment: Thank you. Almost got it, although now Val is not defined. Any suggestions to define val without screwing anything else up? I'm.. tremendously NOOb-ish... I thought it was defined??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were small typos in your code which I fixed.

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#sendButton").click(function(){
        var val = $('#textbox').val();
        $('<li>'+val+'</li>').appendTo('#ulList');
    });
 });
```

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4DCzk/)**

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try. do I still need to devine val?

Comment: @john ofcourse.. if you don't want to define it again and again then keep it as global variable.

Comment: @Mr_Green , Doesn't have to be a global variable, just define it outside the .click() event handler.

Comment: @AbijeetPatro yes I mean the same. Just can't rephrase as you did :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean this?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#sendButton").click(function(){
            var val = $('#textbox').val(); //<-- Here
            $('<li>'+val+'</li>').appendTo('#ulList');
        });
 });
```

syntax error here `$('#textbox').val());` and no assinment to the variable `val` which you probably intend to assign value from the textbox in this statement.

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yatPv/)

Comment: Closer! all my other stuff works now, but now when I try to hit the send button I get this:

Uncaught ReferenceError: val is not defined chatApp.html:57
(anonymous function) chatApp.html:57
le.event.dispatch ChatBuilder.js:2
b.handle

Comment: @john Can you replicate it in a fiddle? which line is causing the error. Try debug the script.

Comment: I am embarrassed to say I have not debugged yet. let me do a quick search for what fiddle is.  How do I assign something to val???

Comment: wow that fiddle thing is COOL! haha. Thank you for sharing that with me.

Answer (score 1):

you need to do something with the value you are retrieving. Change

```
$('#textbox').val());
```

to

```
var val = $('#textbox').val());
```

TD

Comment: IT WORKS! thanks everyone! I wish I could upvote your answers, but my rank is not quite high enough yet. Thanks a bunch

Comment: @john Might I suggest you give Firefox and Firebug a try. Although Chrome is my favorite browser, for development, Firefox and Firebug are much better. I believe you can accept an answer even when you do not have enough rep to upvote. Accepting an answer will also increase your rep I think.

Answer (score 0):

There were two errors. I will point them out with a comment. I had too many )  marks, and I did not define val. look for //here//   and compare that line to my original question.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#sendButton").click(function(){
  //Here//    var val = $('#textbox').val(); //Here//
        $('<li>'+val+'</li>').appendTo('#ulList');
    })
  });

</script>


<h2>Broken Chat</h2>

<input id="textbox" class="draft" type="text"/> <button id="sendButton" class="send">send</button>

<ul id="ulList" class="messages">
  <li id= "userMessage"></li>
</ul>
```